# Labelling columns and lines in a MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a MatrixPlot that I would like to improve by adding labels.

The Matrix is composed with :
- 14 columns,
- 6 lines.

Instead of the graduation of the matrix, I would like to specify this labels :

- for the columns {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"}
- for the lines {"eq1","eq2","eq3","eq4","eq5","eq6"}

**How can I put this labels instead the current graduation ?**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
collabels =  CharacterRange["a", "n"]; 
rowlabels = Row[{"eq", #}] & /@ Range[6];
rowticks = Thread[{Range[6], rowlabels}];
colticks = Thread[{Range[14], collabels}];
dat = RandomInteger[5, {6, 14}];
MatrixPlot[dat, FrameTicks -> {rowticks, colticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use

```
FrameTicks -> {rowticks, colticks,rowticks, colticks}]
```

to label all four sides:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixPlot[dat, FrameTicks -> {None, None, rowticks, colticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I would like to do a slight modification. Instead of the list {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"}, I would like to use a list of variables of my problems T={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n}. So I have tried to do like this map(ToString,T) so as to convert my list of variables into a list of strings but it seems that it doesn't work. Do you have ideas ?

Comment: @Bendesarts `map(...)` isn't valid MMA syntax.

Comment: Perfect! and how can I do to put the rowticks only on the right and the colticks only on the top ?

Comment: @Bendesarts, you can use `FrameTicks -> {None, None, rowticks, colticks}]`.

Comment: @kglr Great! 
A last small question : how can I transform a list like this {a,b,c,...,} in {"a","b",..} not by using ToString because in fact in my variables I have used subscripts but via a simple ?

Comment: @Bendesarts, tick labels do not have to be strings; you should be able to use subscripted symbols. Can you give an example of variables that is giving you trouble?